# Connection between zero covariance of two random variables and their conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, covariance

I had an assignment to find covariance, conditional probability densities and conditional expectations of random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint probability function $f(x,y) = 9x^2y^2$, $0 \le x \le 1$, $0 \le y \le 1 $. I found that $f(x) = 3x^2$, $f(y) = 3y^2$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3/4$, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 3/4$, and $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 9/16$, so $\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) = 0$. Then I found conditional expectations, but my professor said that it is redundant because of zero covariance. Why it was unnecessary? The conditional expectations actually were identical to unconditional ones in my case.

Comment: Well actually it's because of independence. In general if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the conditional expectations will equal the unconditional expectation (e.g. $\Bbb{E}[X\mid Y = y]$ will equal $\Bbb{E}[X]$ for all $y$). And in this example, you can see that $X$ and $Y$ [are independent because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334406/does-a-joint-density-f-x-y-split-uniquely-into-two-marginal-pdfs-f-x) their joint density can be written as purely a function of $x$, times purely a function of $y$.

Comment: Note that in general, just because two random variables have zero covariance, it doesn't mean that the conditional expectations equal the unconditional expectations. For example, if $X$ is standard normal and $Y=X^2$, you can check that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=0$, but $\Bbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]$ changes depending on the value of $x$ (it equals $x^2$).

Comment: thank u for help!